# Form 'onsubmit' not getting called

Tags: javascript, forms

Here's the part of my form:

```
<form name='form-main' onsubmit='return validate()' action='' method='post'>
    <center><input type='submit' onClick='this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();' value='I accept - Download the GM!'/></center>
</form>
```

and here's the `validate` function:

```
function validate()
{
    // this is just to test if it actually shows
    alert('You must not leave any of the fields blank!');
    return false;
}
```

Whenever I hit the submit button, nothing happens, the page just reloads.. I would like it so it shows the alert dialog.

Comment: if you wanna send the form return true.

Comment: You should try to validate forms not on the client side, because a user can change the code easily. Also, check out jQuery, it has really nice form handling, and will make your job easier when you have larger and more complex inputs. [Here's](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) a link to a useful plugin. Good luck!

Comment: Also note, <center> is really old and you should use CSS instead.  HTML is for content, CSS is for layout.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you call the form's `submit` function, the `submit` event is not fired. [This is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) [by design](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm), the assumption is that if you're triggering the submission from code, you've already done any necessary validation. (Note that this is true of the `HTMLFormElement#submit` function; it is *not* necessarily true of the wrappers libraries put around it.)

In your example, I would remove the `click` handler on the button. It's a submit button, so just put any relevant logic in the `submit` event on the form. Alternately, if you prefer, call `validate()` as part of the button's `click`.

Comment: Still not getting the dialog. This is my form now: `<form name='form-main' method='post'>`. And this is the button: `<input type='submit' onClick='validate();' value='I accept - Download the GM!'/>`. Also tried `return validate();`

Comment: @user1667191: The `validate` function must be a global to be used with the old-fashioned DOM0 `onXYZ` attributes. If it is, that will work. Example: http://jsbin.com/ePUgAyo/1 [source](http://jsbin.com/ePUgAyo/1/edit). But again: Don't put this on the button. Put it on the form. That's the better place. (And you will need the `return` and if you want to prevent the form being submitted based on a condition, have `validate` return `false`.)

Comment: @user1667191: Or better yet, use a modern event handler attached via `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` on old versions of IE).

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J! I had it inside <head> and moved it inside <body> and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 12):

You can override the original prototype "submit" method like this:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;

HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function (){ 
   this._submit(); 
   alert('Deddy Is Great :)'); // or fire the onsubmit event manually
};
```

Comment: Your answer is very good and deserves to be up voted. I tried it and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

The onclick event of your submit button is firing immediately before the onsubmit event of your form, and this is disabling subsequent events from propagating and firing, which causes the validate function to never get triggered. You can see this is you remove the `this.disabled=true;` from your code example.

Per the [docs at W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls%3a-the-disabled-attribute):

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events that are
>   queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on
>   the element.

You should remove the click event code from the submit button, and simply allow the function to do what you need it to do, including disabling the button. For example:

```
function validate() {
    // this is just to test if it actually shows
    document.getElementById('sub').disabled=true;
    alert('You must not leave any of the fields blank!');
    return false;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V8he8/)**

Comment: Thanks for the example, going to use this method to disable the button.