# custom JS form submit does not stop onsubmit handler to debug

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to add some logic before form submission. it's work when i click on submit button. but there is another button which submit the form via JavaScript and my logic doesn't call on that. below is the snippet for reference.

```
<form action="text" method="get">
     <input type="submit">
</form> 
<script>
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
        alert('hi');
    };
    //document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```

when i manually click on submit button, alert comes. but after un-commenting the second line `document.forms[0].submit();` nothing comes.

It'll be also helpful to get explanation for this behavior. as i understand submit handler should be trigger on both cases.

any help will be much appreciated.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should jQuery's $(form).submit(); not trigger onSubmit within the form tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag)

Comment: Well detailed answer is given on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847203/form-onsubmit-not-getting-called

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop the default action, you can do this with event.preventDefault();

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `click` event instead.

```
document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();
```