# Div with contentEditable wont post into form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

**Okai, so I have this div:**

```
// DESCRIPTION AREA
$body_html .= "<div id='seq-desc-".$seq_id_d."' contenteditable='true' data-text='Det som skal skje...'>";
$body_html .= $seq_desc_d;
$body_html .= "</div>&nbsp;";
```

**and this textarea:**

```
$body_html .= "<textarea id='seq-desc-area-".$seq_id_d."' name='deta-".$seq_id_d."' style='display: none;'></textarea></td>";
```

**In my form I use the following code to activate my Javascript code:**

```
"<form action='planner_seq_save.php' id='save-".$seq_id_d."' name='save-".$seq_id_d."' method='POST' onsubmit='return getContent".$seq_id_d."'>";
```

`getContent` is defined like this:

```
function getContent'.$seq_id_d.'(){
    document.getElementById("seq-desc-area-'.$seq_id_d.'").value = document.getElementById("seq-desc-'.$seq_id_d.'").innerHTML;
}
```

How come I get an empty return in my database when using POST? 
I use `$_POST['deta-(the id)']` to fetch my post.

**Also I save my form using this code on a standard button. Could this make** `onsubmit` **not work**?

```
onclick='document.forms['save-".$seq_id_d."'].submit();'
```

Been trying to find out what the problem is for a while now, and I really need someone elses opinion.

**UPDATE:**

Using `console.log()` I get no return within the function. So the function isn't running.

Full code can be found [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/7V9y4jh9cn2JKKTZkSv2Xz)

Comment: is `getContent ` being called? have you tried debug using `console.log()` in `getContent `?

Comment: @dann, console.log() isn't outputting anything. So the function isn't running. Could it be disturbed by the onclick function?

Comment: i guess `onsubmit` event only triggered on user action, when you submit form by code (`form.submit()`), the event is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `submit` event is not triggered when triggering the `submit()` method, therefore the `onsubmit` handler is not called. [See another question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847255/1144057).

So you can try removing the `onsubmit` handler and trigger the `getContent` function from the `onclick`'s one:

`onclick='submitForm(id)'`

```
function submitForm(id){
    getContent(id);

    document.forms(id).submit();
}
```

Comment: This can't the problem tough, I have used this lots of places. Got the inspiration from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355583/can-div-with-contenteditable-true-be-passed-through-form

Comment: Update: I tried, still not working. The function isn't running.

Comment: @GjertIngarGjersund, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

- rename function `getContent-'.$seq_id_d.'()` to `getContent_'.$seq_id_d.'()`
- correct textarea id in function `document.getElementById("seq-desc-area-'.$seq_id_d.'").value` to `document.getElementById("seq-deta-area-'.$seq_id_d.'").value`
- correct function call in onsubmit `onsubmit='return getContent-".$seq_id_d."'` to `onsubmit='return getContent_".$seq_id_d."()'`

suppose that is all :)

full code

```
<?php
$seq_id_d = 1;
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
<div id='seq-desc-<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>' contenteditable='true' data-text='Det som skal skje...'>werwerwqrewrqwer</div>
<form id='save-<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>' name='save-<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>' method='POST' onsubmit='return getContent_<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>()'>
<textarea id='seq-deta-area-<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>' name='deta-<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>' style='display: none;'></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
<script>
function getContent_<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>(){
document.getElementById("seq-deta-area-<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>").value = document.getElementById("seq-desc-<?php echo $seq_id_d; ?>").innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1, already changed it. 2, this is a slip from my side, I have 3 fields that I wish to submit. However, just using 1 since they are all the same. So no problem there. 3. done, still not working

Comment: It's not the problem. Se full code parse update on question.

Comment: form onsubmit is with "()" `onsubmit='return getContent".$seq_id_d."()'`?

Comment: Seems that forms onsubmit is not calling if form is submited by javascript. Add getContent to onclick `onclick=\"getContent".$seq_id_d."(); document.forms['save-".$seq_id_d."'].submit();\"`