# Why submit() method didn't trigger onsubmit event?

Tags: javascript

I have a form like below:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="alert('The form was submitted');" >
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Though I clicked the button and indeed it submitted the form, but the `alert` box wasn't shown. That is, the `submit()` method submitted the form but without triggering the `onsubmit` event. What happened? And how should I use `submit()` method to trigger the `onsubmit` event?

Comment: You will need to add a input with type submit button and when you click on it then only your onsubmit will be auto triggered.
add below element to your html and click on it

`<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>`

Comment: btw you can simply use `document.forms[0]` or in the case of a form element as in your code, `this.form`

Comment: Because its a button. It will fire onclick. In onclick, you submitted the form through javascript. You can try to change it to input type submit to see if there is any difference. In that case, you don&#39;t need to call submit through javascript.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the [documentation for the submit method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) is pretty clear that it doesn't trigger onsubmit.

Since any of the following form elements cause a form submit:

```
<input type='submit'>
<input type='button'>
<button>
```

You likely don't need an onclick handler on that button at all

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you can't, please check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847255/8449863

however, please try workaround with hidden submit button:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="alert('The form was submitted');" >
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('submit').click();" >
  <input id="submit" type="submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```